# Java HelloWorld program run

Tags: java, javac

I tried to run my basic HelloWorld.class file from my terminal.

I use the following input:

```
Java HelloWorld.class
```

But it says:

```
Error: Could not find or load "HelloWorld.class"
```

I have tried giving it a directory but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please extend your question with the exact compile & running command.

Comment: remove `.class` extension

Comment: Does `HelloWorld` live in a package?

Comment: which folder is your HelloWorld in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you didn't compiled or run it successufully.you should use

```
 javac HelloWorld.java
```

to complile and

then use

```
 java HelloWorld
```

to run it.
plz check this tutorial http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/

Answer (score 2):

The **class** should be  (Executable Class should definitely contain the main method with same declaration as below)

```
Class MyClassName
{
   // Methods here

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
       // Code here
   }
}
```

To **Compile**, it should be:

```
javac MyClassName.java
```

On successful compilation, `MyClassName.class` would be generated in your folder.

To **run**, it should be

```
java MyClassName
```

In case your java is in say `D:/JavaWorkDir/src`, You need to compile and run from the folder `D:/JavaWorkDir/src`. Also Ensure that your classpath is set appropiately.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because you shouldn't include the `.class` when you run the compiled file.

After you've compiled:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

run using:

```
java HelloWorld
```

(don't do: `java HelloWorld.class`)

Answer (score 0):

Run it as `Java HelloWorld` and not like `Java HelloWorld.class`.
The error `Error: Could not find or load "HelloWorld.class"` is occuring because:

1. The class may have not compiled correctly.
2. The compiled class is not available on the path from where you are trying to run it.
3. Proper classpath is not set for compiling and running the java classes.

Whenever you write a Java Program named `HelloWorld`, you must compile it as:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Once the `HelloWorld.class` class file generated in the same directory where you have your java file, compiled by the compiler, you can run it from console as:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't run it as

```
java HelloWorld.class
```

but

```
java HelloWorld
```

There is no need of `.class` extension.

But note you always have to use `fully qualified name`. So if your class resides in some package say `myPackage` then you need to run

```
java myPackage.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to try hello world you can also try to run it on the NetBeans application and also on Jdoodle.com